# In-place replacement

Tags: sed, awk

I have a CSV. I want to edit the 35th field of the CSV and write the change back to the 35th field. This is what I am doing on bash:

```
awk -F "," '{print $35}' test.csv  | sed -i 's/^0/+91/g'
```

so, I am pulling the 35th entry using awk and then replacing the "0" in the starting position in the string with "+91". This one works perfet and I get desired output on the console.

Now I want this new entry to get written in the file. I am thinking of sed's "in -place" replacement feature but  this fetuare needs and input file. In above command, I cannot provide input file because my primary command is awk and sed is taking the input from awk.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you know that you can use `sub(/^0/,"+91",$35)` in awk? Good luck.

Comment: I ran `awk -F "," {'sub(/^0/, "+91",$35); print $35 '} test.csv` and it does the substitution on the console It does not write the change to the file. BTW, thanks for the info, this was new to me :)

Comment: Thanks. redirecting the output to a new file copies only the 35th column, meaning the edited column. Anyway, i am working on it and will post my answer once I have it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it was way easier with perl than sed/awk. Here it how I got it working `perl -p -i -e 's/\b0(\d{10})\b/\+91$1/g; test.csv`. This answer was provided by one of the monks on perlmonk. But I am still trying to make it work with sed/awk :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should choose one of the two tools. As for `sed`, it can be done as follows:

```
sed -ri 's/^(([^,]*,){34})0([^,]*)/\1+91\3/' test.csv
```

Not sure about `awk`, but @shellter's comment might help with that.

Comment: THis one is not working. But i think i can do some tweaking to your command. Thanks.

Comment: @Dheeraj I'll be happy to help with that if you provide at least one line of sample input.

Comment: @Dheeraj Actually I think I figured out what was wrong, the edited command should work better. Anyway, when asking questions of this kind, please provide some sample input for us to play with.

Comment: Sorry for not getting the sample input. i will make sure to ad in my future questions. Your edited command does not work but thanks for the direction. I will tweak it and hopeful that it will work. Thanks for your time Lev.

Comment: BTW, here is the sample: `foo,foo,foo,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* My Contacts ::: Phone Only,,,,,,,Mobile,01234567899,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`. so in this line i want `01234567899` to change to `+911234567899`

Comment: @Dheerah wait a sec, do you need 1 field in the output or all fields? I thought the former...

Comment: yep. all the field with 35th field edited as per my requirement. Hence i was trying to do "in-place" substitution, because I wanted other all other fields to be as it.

Comment: it was way easier with perl than sed/awk. Here it how I got it working `perl -p -i -e 's/\b0(\d{10})\b/\+91$1/g;` test.csv`. This answer was provided by one of the monks on perlmonk. But I am still trying to make it work with sed/awk :)

Comment: @Dheeraj I edited the answer. Also note that in your example it's 34th field, not 35th, so for the command to work you'll have to change `34` to `33`.

Comment: Thanks. this is working fine. I am answering the question please take a look.

Answer (score 16):

The `in-place` feature of sed is misnamed, as it does not edit the file in place.  Instead, it creates a new file with the same name.  eg:

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ ln -f foo bar
$ ls -i foo bar  # These are the same file
797325 bar  797325 foo
$ echo new-text > foo  # Changes bar
$ cat bar
new-text
$ printf '/new/s//newer\nw\nq\n' | ed foo  # Edit foo "in-place"; changes bar
9
newer-text
11
$ cat bar
newer-text
$ ls -i foo bar  # Still the same file
797325 bar  797325 foo
$ sed -i s/new/newer/ foo   # Does not edit in-place; creates a new file
$ ls -i foo bar
797325 bar  792722 foo
```

Since sed is not actually editing the file in place, but writing a new file and then renaming it to the old file, you might as well do the same.

```
awk ... test.csv | sed ... > test.csv.1 && mv test.csv.1 test.csv
```

There is the misperception that using `sed -i` somehow avoids the creation of the temporary file.  It does not.  It just hides the fact from you.  Sometimes abstraction is a good thing, but other times it is unnecessary obfuscation.  In the case of `sed -i`, it is the latter.  The shell is really good at file manipulation.  Use it as intended.   If you do need to edit a file in place, don't use the streaming version of `ed`; just use `ed`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i 's/[^,]*/+91/35' test.csv
```

EDIT:

To replace the leading zero in the 35th field:

```
sed 'h;s/[^,]*/\n&/35;/\n0/!{x;b};s//+91/' test.csv
```

or more simply:

```
|sed 's/^\(\([^,]*,\)\{34\}\)0/\1+91/' test.csv
```

Comment: It partially does, but it replaces the 35th field with "+91" and omits the remaining digits.

Comment: Wow. I can specify the number of the occurrence as a flag in `s`? What else can be there? I only knew about `g` and `p`...

Answer (score 2):

So, it turned out there are numerous ways to do it. I got it working with sed as below:

`sed -i 's/0\([0-9]\{10\}\)/\+91\1/g' test.csv`

But this is little tricky as it will edit any entry which matches the criteria. however in my case, It is working fine.

Similar implementation of above logic in perl:

`perl -p -i -e 's/\b0(\d{10})\b/\+91$1/g;' test.csv`

Again, same caveat as mentioned above.

More precise way of doing it as shown by  **Lev Levitsky** because it will operate specifically on the 35th field

`sed -ri 's/^(([^,]*,){34})0([^,]*)/\1+91\3/g' test.csv`

For more complex situations, I will have to consider using any of the csv modules of perl.

Thanks everyone for your time and input. I surely know more about sed/awk after reading your replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) installed, you can simply use the `sponge` tool:

```
awk -F "," '{print $35}' test.csv  | sed -i 's/^0/+91/g' | sponge test.csv
```

`sponge` soaks up the input, closes the input pipe (stdin) and, only then, opens and writes to the `test.csv` file.

As of 2015, moreutils is available in package repositories of several major Linux distributions, such as [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/moreutils/), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils) and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/utils/moreutils).

Answer (score 0):

Another perl solution to edit the 35th field in-place:

`perl -i -F, -lane '$F[34] =~ s/^0/+91/; print join ",",@F' test.csv`

These command-line options are used:

- `-i` edit the file in-place
- `-n` loop around every line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with 0
`$F[34]` is the 35 element of the array
`s/^0/+91/` does the substitution